# I have an problem with the function to optimize with lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, lagrange-multiplier

I need help with the restriction of the problem, because i cannot find the function to optimize.

The problem: Find the maximum and minimum distances from the origin to the curve $g\left(x,y\right)=5x^{2}+6xy+5y^{2}=8$

I do not want to solve the problem, just help me find the function to optimize.

Comment: The distance of a point $ \ (x, \ y ) \ $ from the origin is $ \ \sqrt{x^2 \ + \ y^2 } \ $ (applying the "distance formula") .  Since that is always non-negative, however, you can just extremize  $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ $ and obtain the same results.

Comment: Then $f\left(x,y\right)=x^{2}+y^{2}$ is the function to optimize? @RecklessReckoner

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I might mention that since this "rotated conic" has symmetry about the origin, and the function to be extremized does as well,  the points where the extrema occur are symmetrically located about $ \ ( 0, \ 0 ) \ $ .

Comment: Thanks man @RecklessReckoner